# TensorFlow GradientTape.jacobian() run out of GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am now trying to use TF2 to caculate gradients for every single entry of a matirx with the following code:

```py
  with tf.GradientTape() as g:
      g.watch(nn_model.trainable_variables)
      out1 = nn_model(x)
      out2 = nn_model(y)
      matrix = generate (nn_model,out1,out2)

  jac = g.jacobian(matrix,nn_model.trainable_variables)
```

The matrix is pretty big (56x56), and the jacobian step keeps running out of GPU memory. And I have 2 RTX3090 on the server, so is there any technique that I can use to utilize both GPU's memory? Say, I can use up to 2xRTX3090's memory to expand the total capacity.

PS:

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf

class NN(tf.keras.Model):
  """The convolutional network used to compute the agent's policy."""

  def __init__(self,
               num_actions,
               name = None,
               dropout = 0.0,
               rand_conv = False,
               projection = True,
               **kwargs):
    super(NN, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self._dropout = dropout
    self._num_actions = num_actions
    self.rand_conv = None
    self._projection = projection
    # Defining layers.
    activation_fn = tf.keras.activations.relu
    self.conv0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        32, [8, 8],
        strides=4,
        padding='same',
        activation=activation_fn,
        name='Conv')
    self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        64, [4, 4],
        strides=2,
        padding='same',
        activation=activation_fn,
        name='Conv1')
    self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        64, [3, 3],
        strides=1,
        padding='same',
        activation=activation_fn,
        name='Conv2')
    self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    self.dense0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=activation_fn)
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=activation_fn)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_actions, name='fully_connected')

  @tf.function
  def call(self, state, training=True):
    x = self.representation(state, projection=False)
    if training:
      x = tf.nn.dropout(x, rate=self._dropout)
    x = self.dense2(x)
    if self._num_actions == 1:
      x = tf.squeeze(x, axis=-1)
    return x

  def representation(self, state, projection=True):
    x = tf.cast(state, tf.float32)
    if self.rand_conv is not None:
      x = self.rand_conv(x)
    x = self.conv0(x)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.dense0(x)
    if projection and self._projection:
      x = self.dense1(x)
    return x

nn_model = NN(
      num_actions=2, dropout=float(0.0), rand_conv=True,
      projection=True)

fake1 = tf.random.uniform([56,60,60,2])
fake2 = tf.random.uniform([56,60,60,2])

with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(nn_model.trainable_variables)
    out1 = nn_model.representation(fake1)
    out2 = nn_model.representation(fake2)
    # Say we use a cosine-smilarity to 
    cos = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=2, reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
    m = cos(tf.expand_dims(out1, 1), tf.expand_dims(out2, 0))

jac = g.jacobian(m,nn_model.trainable_variables)
```

And it reports hundreds of lines error info, I guess the main idea is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3136,56,8,8,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[node gradient_tape/ReluGrad_5/pfor/Tile (defined at /RLgen-MaaM/jumping_task/train_minimal_debug.py:82) ]]
```

Sys Info:

I'm using TF2.5 with ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be great if you produced a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you better. If you included the full stack trace of the error message that would also help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TCArlen Hi, thx for your reply! I uploaded a version for minimal reproducible example.